# Running a ruby sinatra postgreSQL error

Tags: ruby, bash, postgresql, sinatra

I have been trying to run my ruby app that previously was run on my MACbook. Currently, I am using a Windows OS and bash. PostgreSQL is installed. So are Sinatra and Ruby of course. Every single time while running the app I receive this error

```
$ ruby app.rb
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- sinatra/contrib/all (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
`require'
    from app.rb:2:in
```

Here's my app.rb file

```
require('sinatra')
require('sinatra/contrib/all')
require_relative('controllers/collection_controller')
require_relative('controllers/product_controller')

get '/' do
  erb(:index)
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you run "bundle install --without production," does Sinatra install successfully?

Comment: @MitchStewart actually don't use a bundle. But I have encountered a new issue. I have managed to run the app with sinatra and ruby but now my database fails. I get this 

    `C:/Users/Blazej W/Desktop/KurakClothing-Owner-App-ver1.0-master/db/sql_runner.rb :10:in `ensure in run': undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  clone from C:/Users/Blazej W/Desktop/KurakClothing-Owner-App-ver1.0-master/db/sql_runner.rb:10:in `run'  from C:/Users/Blazej W/Desktop/KurakClothing-Owner-App-ver1.0-master/models/product.rb:87:in `delete_all'  from seeds.rb:5:in `<main>'`

Comment: Don't ask a new question in a comment. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: "'require': cannot load such file" means it's not installed in Ruby. What does `gem list sinatra` show you? Copy that output and paste it into your question, formatting it appropriately for readability.